# Page.Request on asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to execute this code, except the page_load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    var contextToken = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(Page.Request);
```

in a controller

```
var contextToken = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(Page.Request);
```

However I get this error

> Error  1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Request.get'

How can I get the current page request in MVC?

Update 1:

I changed to:

```
 var contextToken = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(HttpContext.Current.Request);
```

Now I got:

> Error 2   'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for
>   'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

What assembly do I need?

These are my usings

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI;
```

Comment: get rid the `.Current` and just use `TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(HttpContext.Request)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a `Page` in ASP.NET MVC, this is an ASP.NET Web Forms concept (inheritance from `Page`). When you are working within MVC, you are in the scope of a `Controller` class which contains a reference to the current `Context`.

Instead, in MVC, use: `HttpContext.Request`, like that:

```
var contextToken = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(HttpContext.Request);
```

Comment: To be fair, MVC is built upon ASP.NET, a page is more a WebForms concept. (please fact check)

Comment: This is true and this is why you have the `HttpContext.Current.Request` in MVC.

Comment: @gunr217122: you are right. It's called ASP.NET Web Forms now.

Comment: do I have the wrong reference?? Error 2 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @L.V.SharepointArchitect, edit your post with any information you have. It is harder to read in the comments.